# Nginx+uWSGI Error : request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am using nginx+uwsgi combination for a Post API.

API end point is expected to receive 3000 reqeust/10 seconds

Source Machines are not able to POST requests sometimes with error

```
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have following settings on nginx

```
           location / {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
            include uwsgi_params;
           }
```

and

```
     http {
               tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 2;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
}

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
```

Comment: Give it a try to increase your timeout and a run a test.

Comment: What's the value of `worker_connections` in nginx?

Comment: @pako `worker_connections 1024`

Comment: @hardcoder is this resolved? I am also getting same error for high traffic flow